# fatal: unable to stat "file": Permission denied

Tags: java, android, git, github

I searched and tried answer but problem didn't solve, I git init into android project and after making first push, I changed alot of things removed added new files and fonts (I don't remember if i git added during this) now when I ready to pus i ran command git status I see files in red as untract files, then I ran git add . but Im getting this error:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/app.iml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
fatal: unable to stat 'app/src/main/res/drawable/slide_thre.jpg':
Permission denied
```

the file slide_thre.jpg I deleted way before git add wen I was working but its still showing this error, I dont know if its cached

I tried closing IDE before git add and tried other solution but didn't work

[image: start: git status ->]

[image: git status -end]

Comment: `git rm` or `git reset`... If you delete a file, you still need to commit the action of deleting it

Comment: git rm filename?

Comment: That'll remove from tracking the file, yes, but that depends if you ever added it in the first place. Please show the output of the git status command

Comment: added image of git status

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure why `slide_thre.jpg` is giving you problems if it's not listed there

Comment: See this?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161297/git-error-fatal-unable-to-stat-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Is there two git projects here? I'm confused... The general solution here is to stage the deletion of the file and commit it. I don't know why you'd have a permission issue, but you could run CMD as administrator if you want

Comment: no its just one and when im trying to remove it says no path specified found

Comment: I don't know what command you just ran, but seems like you didn't provide a path

Comment: If you use `git checkout -- <file>` does that undelete it?

Comment: it saying unknown option

Answer (score 0):

> Try closing any programs that have the folder open, such as editors,
>   explorer windows, command prompts, and FTP programs. This always fixes
>   the issue for me on Windows.

You can also try "invalidate & restart" your IDE, that should clean the caches.
Lastly, try disabling the virus checker just to see if it would let you through then.

[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8813659/5719764)

Answer (score 0):

did you close your photoviewer application which open slide_thre.jpg?

Comment: Yes i did, even closed android studio

Comment: try re-add your file : git rm slide_thre.jpg then add, git add. and commit again

Comment: I did it saying path specified not recognized, thinking of deleting .git folder and doing git init again